# how to lock Dependency version in maven?

Tags: maven, spring-cloud, zipkin

I already have parent management in my app
springboot version is 2.1.7
springcloud version is Greenwich.SR2

I want import this

```
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
```

but final version is 2.1.X

how to lock dependency version

Answer (score 0):

You have everything messed up.you're using sleuth in version 2.2.x that requires boot 2.2.x or 2.3.x and is part of the hoxton release train but you're using greenwich release train with an incompatible version of boot. Please don't use explicit version of cloud projects but get them from the bom. If you want to use latest sleuth, please use latest boot and latest release train

Comment: Use boot 2.2.x with hoxton train and remove version for sleuth